# What is a price gap exactly? candle shadows does matter in this pattern or not?

Tags: technical-analysis, chart

According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/05/playinggaps.asp), gaps are defined as:

> Spaces on a chart that emerge when the price of the financial
> instrument significantly changes with little or no trading in-between.

Considering this definition, I guess that we should look for positions where no trading has happened. Therefore, the following is definitely a gap:

[image]

However, I have seen that in some tutorials that the price candle which is connected to the past candle by its shadow is also considered a gap. For example, in the below chart, the last candle is marked as a gap by a tutor.

[image]
Is it correct to think of this candle as a gap? I think that it is not a gap because the shadow has filled the gap between the last candle and the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to think of this candle as a gap?

Yes, because there is no specific definition. Is the move in the chart above significant enough to be a gap? What volume of trading counts as little?

The body of the candle represents the open and close, so when there is no overlap between candle bodies it represents a gap where the price jumped between the closing tick of one candle and the opening tick of the next.